# how can I include an image or icon a placeholder alongside with text on a input form

Tags: html, css, forms, input, placeholder

I'm struggling to include an icon as a placeholder in an input form alongside a text

```
<input type="email" placeholder=" src="image source" your email">
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Placeholder is just for plain text, I don't think it's possible for an image.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe its possible to put an image inside but its possible to put a unicode in it. Do you mean like this??

```html
<input type="email" placeholder=" &#9993 your email" >
```